# SonarQube not apply analyzing to the root project

Tags: java, gradle, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I need to make analyzing only root project, and ignore nested sub module, but it d

So I have this hierarchy:

```
ProjectMain
 -src
 -subProjectAngular
  settings.gradle
```

My configuration **settings.gradle**

```
  rootProject.name="ProjectMain" 
  include 'subProjectAngular'
```

I need to make analyzing only root project, and ignore nested sub module, but I got:

```
A multi-module project can't have source folders, so 'C:\Users\vagrant\develop-2\site\Source\Site\Vessels\src\main\java' won't be used for the analysis. If you want to analyse files of this folder, y
ou should create another sub-module and move them inside it.
```

Then I tried to add multi module configuration:

```
systemProp.sonar.projectKey=site
systemProp.sonar.projectName=vessels-test
systemProp.sonar.projectBaseDir=.
systemProp.sonar.sources=src

systemProp.sonar.modules=javamodule, angularmodule

systemProp.javamodule.sonar.projectName=vessels
systemProp.javamodule.sonar.sources=src
systemProp.javamodule.sonar.projectBaseDir=.
systemProp.javamodule.sonar.language=java

systemProp.angularmodule.sonar.projectName=angular
systemProp.angularmodule.sonar.projectBaseDir=.
systemProp.angularmodule
```

but got message at UI: **no analysis has been performed**

*It's only works when I remove definishion of subproject from **settings.gradle**, and remove all submodule confguration*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This configuration is not support yet in SonarQube.

But the good news is that this will change with SonarQube 6.4 (expect in early May 2017). See the following tickets:

- [SONAR-6724](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-6724)
- [SONARGRADL-5](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARGRADL-5)